# laravel lists is giving wrong ids for the column values

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I am fetching a list of rosters

```
$rostersList = Roster::where('school_id', $this->schoolId)->get()->lists('id', 'name');
$rostersList->prepend('Select Roster');
```

but the ids always start from 0,1,2 why is that? However according to the where condition the returned list should not be starting from 0 or 1 but from 4. What can be the possible issue here?

Comment: You probably do not want to get all the data, as you need only `id` and `name`, so you can use `Rostere::where()->lists('id', 'name')` without  calling `get()`. You'll have less data to fetch.

Comment: @Skysplit thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you prepend a single value without assigning a key with it, the collection gets re-keyed.

[Laravel prepend](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-prepend) lets you pass a second parameter to use as the key.

So you would want something like:

```
$rostersList->prepend('Select Roster', '');
```